# How to apply css in internet explorer COM object?

Tags: c++, css, internet-explorer, com

I write in Qt but it shouldn't matter since I only want to use COM funcs
This is how I load the IE.

```
QAxWidget* axieBrowser= new QAxWidget(ui->centralWidget);
axieBrowser->setControl(QString::fromUtf8("{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}"));
axieBrowser->dynamicCall("Navigate(const QString&)", "www.google.com");
```

And now I want to apply css to all pages that I open from this widget.
For example:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

In Qt if I use Qt Webkit, I can achieve this using

```
ui->webView->page()->settings()->setUserStyleSheetUrl(myCss);
```

How can I do this using IE COM?

Answer (score 0):

in Qt I managed with the following codes

```
IDispatch* val = axieBrowser->property("Document").value<IDispatch*>();
QAxObject * obj = new QAxObject((IUnknown*)val);
if (obj)
{
    QAxObject * result = obj->querySubObject("createStyleSheet(QString, int)", "", 0);
    result->setProperty("cssText", "body {  margin:0;   overflow:hidden;    opacity: 0.4;}");
}
```